# When I don't use mysql GROUP BY, I only get one row of data

Tags: mysql, relational-database

new to mysql here. I am using mysql version 5.6.25-enterprise-commercial-advanced, and I have tables

```
mysql> select * from Department;
+-------+--------------+
| DepID | DepName      |
+-------+--------------+
|     1 | English      |
|     2 | Math         |
|     3 | History      |
|     4 | French       |
|     5 | Geography    |
|     6 | Drawing      |
|     7 | Architecture |
+-------+--------------+
```

and

```
mysql> select * from Student;
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| StudID | StudName | StudentAge | DepID |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
|      1 | Alice    |         21 |     2 |
|      2 | Alfred   |         20 |     3 |
|      3 | Henry    |         19 |     3 |
|      4 | Jacobs   |         22 |     5 |
|      5 | Bob      |         20 |     4 |
|      6 | Shane    |         22 |     4 |
|      7 | Linda    |         24 |     4 |
|      8 | Stacy    |         20 |     1 |
|      9 | Wolfred  |         21 |     2 |
|     10 | Sandy    |         25 |     1 |
|     11 | Colin    |         18 |     1 |
|     12 | Maria    |         19 |     3 |
|     13 | Ziva     |         20 |     5 |
|     14 | Mark     |         23 |     5 |
|     15 | Fred     |         25 |     2 |
|     16 | Vic      |         25 |  NULL |
|     17 | Nick     |         25 |  NULL |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
```

I am using a query:

```
SELECT Department.DepName, AVG(Student.StudentAge) AS AvgStudAge
FROM Student
RIGHT JOIN Department
ON Student.DepID = Department.DepID;
```

that only results in a single row:

```
+---------+------------+
| DepName | AvgStudAge |
+---------+------------+
| English |    21.2667 |
+---------+------------+
```

...but I feel that I should be getting all the other rows too, with the DepName column giving me something like "English" or "Math" and the associated aggregate age being the average age of all students associated with that department. Why does it only return a row for English?

I have actually found that inserting the following line of code `GROUP BY DepName;` at the end of my previous query gives me what I want, but I don't understand why I should have to GROUP BY anything.

Any clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: the way i see it, mysql is confused and does whatever it wants. you aren't telling it to group by, it can't read your mind, perhaps a syntax error would be better

Comment: `AVG()` is an [`aggregation function`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks, that's a very helpful link. i'll be sure to check it for more detailed information which my book doesn't cover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query:

```
SELECT Department.DepName, AVG(Student.StudentAge) AS AvgStudAge
FROM Student
RIGHT JOIN Department
ON Student.DepID = Department.DepID;
```

By using an aggregate like `AVG` without also using `GROUP BY`, SQL treats this as an average of all of the data returned, irrespective of department.

The `DepName` that MySql is showing on the single row returned is arbitrarily the first value returned. Other than MySql, an ANSI Compliant RDBMS will raise an error for this query, as either ALL columns selected must be introduced with an aggregate (if there is no `GROUP BY`), or, all non-aggregated columns must be in the `GROUP BY` clause (when grouped). MySql is annoyingly tolerant in this regard and this can lead to bugs.

Example of Average Student age per Department:

```
SELECT Department.DepName, AVG(Student.StudentAge) AS AvgStudAge
FROM Student
RIGHT JOIN Department
ON Student.DepID = Department.DepID
GROUP BY Department.DepName;
```

Average Student Age of all students:

```
SELECT AVG(Student.StudentAge) AS AvgStudAge
FROM Student;
```

[Examples of aggregates with / without `GROUP BY` here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c213/1)

Answer (score -1):

Just add Group By in the last  `GROUP by Department.DepID`, you will have all departments average